# How to write a pyspark dataframe into s3 row wise

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
|id        |     enddt|   startdt|diff    |bill_dt   |val|
+----------+----------+----------+--------+----------+---+
|      1234|2021-02-12|2020-05-17|     200|2020-05-17|   |
|      1234|2021-02-12|2020-05-17|     200|2020-06-17|   |
|      1234|2021-02-12|2020-05-17|     200|2020-06-18|   |
|      1234|2021-02-12|2020-05-17|     200|2020-06-19|   |
|      1234|2021-02-12|2020-05-17|     200|2020-06-20|   |
|      1234|2021-02-12|2020-05-17|     200|2020-06-21|   |
```

I want to write each row as parquet file in s3 in the below directory:

```
bucket_name/bill_dt/id.parquet
```

ex:

```
bucket_name/2020-05-17/1234/1234.parquet
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can control the name of the parquet file written.
What you can do, is `partitionBy` the `id` column and that way you'll have partitions in the `s3` bucket.
Example -

`df.write.partitionBy('id').parquet(S3_PATH)`

Number of partitions you'll have is the number of distinct `id` records.